# Change value of a textbox, compared to another text box value with a ratio

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET C#.

With Javascript, I need to change the value of a textbox, when another text box value changes with the ratio of 3:2.

For example, if the value in a text is 150, the other textbox value should be 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fill() {
        document.getElementsByName('txt2')[0].value) = (document.getElementsByName('txt1')[0].value) * (2 / 3);
    }
</script>
```

**Code in body tag:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>    
    <%--The text boxes must have numeric values--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onchange="javascript:fill();"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change() {    
    var t1Val = (document.getElementById("t1")).value;
    (document.getElementById("t2")).value = ((t1Val * 2) / 3);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="t1" type="text" onchange="change()"/>
<input id="t2" type="text"/>

</body>
</html>
```

If is there any validation you need you can write inside change() function.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdd63/1/

Comment: Please provide more context in your answer. Something more than just a link

Comment: i want input id in c# . but i am not able to get it . how can i get input id . if i give runat="server" it will work fine . but javascript wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `onchange` or `onkeyup` events on the text box

Add the following java-script function to your html

```
function ChangeValue() {
    const txtValOne_value = document.getElementById('txtval1').value
    if (txtValOne_value) {
        document.getElementById('txtval2').value = txtValOne_value*2/3;
    }
}
```

then add two text-boxes with ids txtval1,txtval2 to your html, add `onkeyup="ChangeValue();` to the first one